# How get one row into LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables : actions, mobiles, users, location.

I need to get all the actions (I have 5 rows), from them I must get the user information, location and mobile table, get 1 single row sorted by date of update.

This is a sql:

```
SELECT MAX(a.created_at) as created_at, a.user_id, u.name,
u.created_at as user_createad_at,l.name as location_name, pn.user_id, pn.brand, pn.version, pn.updated_at

FROM actions AS a
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations as l ON l.id = a.location_id

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_at) as updated_at, model, brand, version
   FROM mobiles as pn
   GROUP BY user_id, model, brand, version, updated_at
   ORDER BY updated_at DESC

) as pn ON u.id = pn.user_id

WHERE 1

GROUP BY a.user_id, location_name, pn.brand, pn.version, pn.updated_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

The SQL is good, but I can't get the MAX row from table mobiles
If execute the sql, this return

MY QUERY return this:

[image]

I need this result:
[image]

My example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuio9RxxCN7XiVAsZjHMUG/2 (updated), here

Comment: The rows differs in `version` field. What record must be returned? If with greatest version - do the same with `version` like with `updated_at`.

Comment: I need to get the row that has the most recent update (table mobiles), with the fields, brand, version and other, for the example I only showed 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mXaxiP9PKDhUhnfSfpPPXt/0):

```
SELECT
    a.created_at,
    a.user_id,
    u.name,
    u.created_at as user_createad_at,
    l.name as location_name,
    pn.user_id,
    pn.brand,
    pn.version,
    pn.updated_at
FROM actions a
LEFT JOIN (
  -- latest entry for each user
  SELECT m1.*
  FROM mobiles m1
  LEFT JOIN mobiles m2 ON m1.user_id = m2.user_id
    AND m1.updated_at < m2.updated_at
  WHERE m2.id IS NULL
  ) pn ON a.user_id = pn.user_id
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations as l ON l.id = a.location_id
;
```

Comment: @Alexd2 I don't know. You should test it. I'd believe it should be fine if there are proper indexes.

Comment: thee perfomance is bad :( , the table mobiles has 20 000 rows, the time response is over 1min or more.